# Modifying rendering intent in an embedded color profile?

Tags: color-profile

I make a mistake on my scanning and save the image with the wrong rendering intent inside the embedded color profile. I want the rendering intent to clip all the out-of-gamut color to nearest hue without touching any in-gamut color, so I should be using `relative colorimetric` instead of `perceptual`, which desaturate the whole image in favors of the out-out-gamut color.

Can I still be able to modify the image's embedded color profile at this stage?

Comment: Dont you mean absolute?

Comment: The intent is afaik applied when doing the conversion. Once the image is converted it doesn't remember which intent was used. Only the numbers and name of the profile remains. But I don't really understand how this problem occurs. When you scan, your scanning has some profile. Do you then convert to some other profile when saving? I would keep the original profile until I need to make either a PDF for print using some CMYK profile or a JPG for web using sRGB.

Comment: @Wolff I scan my image with Silverfast. In the CMS setting, I set the `input` to my scanner calibration profile, `internal` to `ProPhoto` and `rendering intent` to `perceptual`. And then I scan it in 48 bit saving to a TIFF file. I haven't convert it to any other format, I want to modify the color profile of this TIFF.

Comment: @joojaa I read that `absolute` will change the white point also?

Comment: Changing rendering intent does not do anything for an image. The data is still the data.

Comment: @joojaa But doesn't rendering intent affect how my ProPhoto image look on an sRGB monitor?

Comment: @reddy yes offcourse if your viewer is correcting the image. But it does not affect your underlying data in any way the image still has the same data values.

Comment: @joojaa I want to change how it looks on my monitor when viewing the TIFF file.